# Does $x^T T(y) = y^T T(x)$ imply that $T$ is a linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, operator-theory

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ an operator satysfying:
\begin{equation}
 x^T T(y) = y^T T(x) ~~~~\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{equation}

Does it imply that $T$ is a linear operator, i.e. that $T$ can be written as $T(x) = Ax$ for some $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's true. You can show it even a bit more generally. Take a real vector space $V$ with a scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. Then take an operator $T:V\to V$ such that $\langle x,Ty\rangle=\langle y,Tx\rangle=\langle Tx,y\rangle\quad\forall x,y\in V$. We show that $T$ is a linear operator:

Let $x\in V$, $y_1,y_2\in V$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $$\langle x,T(ay_1+y_2)\rangle=\langle Tx,ay_1+y_2\rangle=a\langle Tx, y_1\rangle+\langle Tx,y_2\rangle=\\
=a\langle x, Ty_1\rangle+\langle x,Ty_2\rangle=\langle x,aTy_1+Ty_2\rangle$$
Since $x$ was arbitrary it implies that $T(ay_1+y_2)=aTy_1+Ty_2$

In your case the vector space is just $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the scalar product is the usual dot product, so $\langle x,y\rangle=x^Ty$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

This assertion is true. Note for $z, x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
z^\top (T(x+\lambda y)) = (x+\lambda y)^\top T(z) = x^\top T(z) + \lambda y^\top T(z) = z^\top (T(x) + \lambda T(y))
$$
Hence
$$
z^\top \big(T(x+\lambda y ) - T(x) - \lambda T(y) \big) = 0
$$
for all $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. So choose
$$
z = T(x+\lambda y ) - T(x) - \lambda T(y) 
$$
to see that
$$
\lVert T(x+\lambda y ) - T(x) - \lambda T(y) \rVert^2 = 0,
$$
i.e.
$$
T(x+\lambda y) = T(x) + \lambda T(y).
$$

Comment: That norm trick is nice. (+1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!